# What is the way to push data from a callback to a Kotlin coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Suppose I want to use a cache in a [DownloadQueue](https://gist.github.com/elizarov/34de14377c6a1caf50d560b35a47adc0#file-downloadqueue-kt-L31) like example.
The joy of coroutines there is that a simple data structure (e.g. `HashMap`) can be used in a single threaded algorithm.

However I want to use a limited cache, and evict extra entries to a slower persistent storage.
For instance, I can take `Guava` + `CacheBuilder` + `RemovalListener`: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#removal-listeners

Here's a problem: `RemovalListener` is a non-suspended callback, so there's no way to push data to `Channels` or whatever from the callback.

```
// This is placed in a suspend context (e.g. within `actor`)
val cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(1000)
    .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .removalListener<Key, Value> { n ->
        expireChannel.sendBlocking(n.value!!) // <-- could sendBlocking be used here???
    }.build<Key, Value>()
```

As far as I understand, `runBlocking` blocks the execution of a current thread, thus it blocks current coroutine, and it won't be able to receive/handle the data.

Is there a way to make `RemovalListener`-like callbacks coroutine-friendly?

I can imagine a workaround of using an unbounded queue that is populated by a `RemovalListener` while the coroutine in question eventually checks the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to not block the removal listener (and thus break the cache) is to have a buffered channel. This means two changes:

1. Create the `SendChannel` with a non-zero capacity, see [`Channel(capacity)`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-channel/index.html) to consider the different behaviors. It mostly depends on what the behavior should be if more items expire than the consumer can handle.
2. Use `SendChannel.offer()` instead of `SendChannel.sendBlocking()`. If it returns `false` you can implement backup behavior like logging the failure so you can figure out what the best balance between memory and losing events is.

Comment: Well, `Channel(capacity==cache_size_capacity*2+42)` should be "enough" for my case since the items are put via single thread (==coroutine), so there can't (shouldn't) suddenly expire lots of objects, so all the expired objects should fit into the buffer, and the coroutine could select from the expired channel first.